# Do operations on both input and select in one jquery line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this working code

```
$('input[name='+ string[1] +']').css({'background':input_accept_icon});
```

As you can see input with some name get's some new css.

Now I want to place both input and select elements in the same line.

I am trying this and other things but it's not working for now

```
$('fieldset > :tags(input,select)[name='+ string[1]+']').css({'background':input_accept_icon});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your markup, you might want to use the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector. It matches `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements:

```
$(":input[name=" + string[1] + "]").css("background", input_accept_icon);
```

Comment: only one thing Frederic , please change ',' to ':' after "background" cause it's an error.  with ':' the code will work, with ',' won't.

Comment: @David, ah, that's because I also removed the curly braces :) I tend to use the two-argument form of `css()` and avoid passing an object when setting only one style property.

Comment: Oh, now I see. By the way can you tell me the difference ? your style looks better. less things to write but what for do I need then those curly braces ?

Comment: Passing an object is useful if you want to set multiple properties in a single call to `css()`, for instance `$("selector").css({ "color": "red", "font-weight": "bolder" });`.

Answer (score 2):

Both elements have the same name? Then you could do:

```
$('input, select').filter('[name="'+ string[1]+'"]')
```

or if you insist on `fieldset`:

```
$('fieldset').children('input, select').filter('[name="'+ string[1]+'"]');
```

Of course you can also build one long selector which gets quite unreadable:

```
 $('fieldset > input[name="'+ string[1]+'"], fieldset >  select[name="'+ string[1]+'"]')
```

If the name is only related to the input:

```
$('input[name="'+ string[1]+'"], select')
```

---

`:tags` is not a built-in pseudo-selector afaik.

Comment: thing is that only one of them will have this name. and I want to write both so only the one which will has this name will change. other will be fake and will stay unchanged. can u help me with such code ?

Comment: @David: Yes, the first three will do.

Comment: thanks for the help but Frédérics way is more easy for me :) just adding ':' to initial code :)